# More Explanation on File Sharing

Tags: nfs, sharing

In a recent question about configuring file sharing between Ubuntu computers, someone gave the following helpful answer:

> Samba is intended for sharing between windows and ubuntu. For sharing in between
> Ubuntu I would suggest nfs. See help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-file-
> system.html Takes about 10 min. to setup. –  Rinzwind yesterday

I went to that page and followed the instructions until I got to:

> You can configure the directories to be exported by adding them to the /etc/exports
> file. For example:
>
> /ubuntu  *(ro,sync,no_root_squash)
> /home    *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
> You can replace * with one of the hostname formats. Make the hostname declaration as
> specific as possible so unwanted systems cannot access the NFS mount.

The page mentions "the directories to be 'exported.'"
Does the word exported mean the same thing as "shared," because prior to that the page talked about sharing, then uses "exported."

Second, what does the line mean, "You can replace * with one of the hostname formats"?

Does this refer to the shared name I intend to use?

Third, if my directory name has a space, should I put the path in double quotes ("/media/****/6CCC5DC2CC5*****/Media Server")?

Fourth, if I should have added these comments to the original post that I saw, please advise. I understood that further questions were not to be appended in that location.

Thanks for any help. My learning at this point feels like I'm drinking from a fire hose.

Raif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the word exported mean the same thing as "shared,"

Yes, it does.

> Third, if my directory name has a space, should I put the path in double quotes ("/media/****/6CCC5DC2CC5*****/Media Server")?

Yes, you should.

> Second, what does the line mean, "You can replace * with one of the hostname formats"?

You can limit what each hostname is permitted to do, ex. host a may mount the export (=share) readonly, host b may mount read/write..
The hostname format may be  specified by using a dns name, ip, ip range...

> I understood that further questions were not to be appended in that location.

Correct, you open new questions for... well, new questions :-)